# Python MySQL library error. (Can't connect to MySQL server on '%-.100s:%u')

Tags: python, mysql

So I am trying to connect to a database from a python script. I'm trying to use the MySQL library.

Every time I run the connector, I get this error:

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '%-.100s:%u' (%s) (Warning: %u format: a number is required, not str)

This is my code for it. It's a standard connection line.

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='default', password='default',
                              host='default',
                              database='default')
cnx.close()
```

The host format looks like this:

> server-server.dev.company.com\IN11

Any value I put in these are coming back the same error, so I suspect it's some configuration issue.

Any help would be appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

the connector, wants a host, that he can resolve,

default is not one of them, use instead localhost for example or an ipadress like 192.168.1.1

```
import mysql.connector


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
   host='localhost',
   user='root',
   password='password',
   port=3306
  )
cnx.close()
```

Comment: I added default for reading purposes. I put my proper credentials in, which I've confirmed work fine. I've updated the post to address in what format my host name is in

Comment: Replace in my code, your credentials one by one and see where it give an error

Comment: It's the host name that it causes the error to. It doesn't like the format of it I guess but not sure how to fix it:

ABC-ABC.devfg.company.com\IN11

Comment: get rid of the backslash and all behind as i wrote it must be a url that can be resolved not a webadress

Comment: The `\IN` is a *path* on the host, is it not? The host is `abc- ... .com`.

Comment: That is correct. I do need the \IN11 in order to connect to the database on tablebase, can't connect to it otherwise. I am getting a connection refused when I remove that part of it on the script

Comment: That sounds odd; and pointing to a setup issue.

Comment: you don't need the path as mysql is a ser4voce that listens on port 3306 on the ipadress no path at all, that is why you get the error

Comment: Also it  is because of the security re4asosn, that sql server aren't open to the internet. you shpould chekc  with your provider about how to access the database

Comment: In my case it was a DNS resolution issue in k8s.